# Permissions of files shared via VirtualBox Shared Folders are not shown correctly in VM

Tags: permissions, virtualbox, chmod

I'm running VirtualBox; host and VM (guest) are both Ubuntu 20.04. I've shared the whole file system of the host (ext4) via VirtualBox Shared Folders capability for VM. I had to add my user on the VM to the vboxsf group. Otherwise, I couldn't access the folder. The shared folder is mounted automatically in `/media/sf_ROOT`. Now, when I chdir to `/media/sf_ROOT/home/...`, I see that the files' permissions are 770! and it's different from 664 on the host.

Why? How can I make VB to show the files' permissions correctly, the same as what they are in the host? Even if I use `chmod` in VM, they're not shown correctly, although they're affected on the files which are located on the host correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the problem is that the the user id and group id on the host are different than the uid/gid on the vbox guest. You can check that with the `id` command run on the host and guest. If they differ, the easiest approach may be to change your uid/gid to make them match. If that's not allowed, you can try to manually mount the shared disk with the uid/gid options - see [mount.vboxsf](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man8/mount.vboxsf.8.html) for details. In the following, insert your own uid and gid instead of 1000/1000

```
sudo mount -t vboxsf -o uid=1000,gid=1000 vbox_share_name /mnt/share_mount_point
```

If that works, and you want to automount it, you can add this to your `/etc/fstab`

```
vbox_share_name /mnt/share_mount_point vboxsf uid=1000,gid=1000 0 0
```

Since you note that you're share the whole host file system with the guest, this may remap uid/gid on files your don't intend to have changed so keep that in mind.